# How to render QPlainTextEdit content to QPixmap with colors?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qt4.8, qplaintextedit

I was successfully using following code to render the content of a QTextEdit to QPixmap. But this fails for QPlainTextEdit. When I use QPlainTextEdit instead of QTextEdit, it rendered the content without any colors (all in black/white).

```
QPixmap* pixmap = new QPixmap(width, height);

QPainter* painter = new QPainter(pixmap);
painter->fillRect( 0, 0, width, height, QColor(247, 247, 247) );
painter->setRenderHints(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform |
                        QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing |
                        QPainter::TextAntialiasing);

m_pTextEdit->document()->drawContents(painter);
```

How can we render the content of a QPlainTextEdit with colors?
Please note,

- If we set text as html in the QPlainTextEdit then it generates colored output.
- I'm using `QSyntaxHighlighter::setFormat` function to set the text colors.

I'm using
Qt4.8.5, VS2008, Windows7

Comment: may be you can try this  QPixmap pixmap(m_pTextEdit->size());
 m_pTextEdit->render(&pixmap); for more info http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#render-2

Comment: @Kunal I will try, but my best guess is, it will only render the visible area, not the entire document.

Comment: I want to achieve the same thing, have you found any solutions?

Comment: @BillYan, No, I haven't found a way. I had to satisfy with a black and white image. Will keep you informed if I find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after investigation, I have found a solution.

basically, the QPlainTextEdit widget only draws the part of the content that is visible. Therefore, we can't use QWidget->render to get the entire content rendered. But we can do this by a modified version of the QPlainTextEdit's paintEvent Function:

```
void TextEditor::getScreenshot(QPixmap &map)
{
    QPainter painter(&map);

    int offset = 0;
    block = document()->firstBlock();

    while (block.isValid())
    {
        QRectF r = blockBoundingRect(block);
        QTextLayout *layout = block.layout();

        if (!block.isVisible())
        {
            offset += r.height();
            block = block.next();
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            layout->draw(&painter, QPoint(0,offset));
        }

        offset += r.height();

        block = block.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. I Will test it.